# Using the OSGi API, how do I find out if a given bundle is a fragment?

Tags: osgi, bundle, osgi-fragment

In the OSGi API, a call to [BundleContext.getBundles()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getBundles%28%29) returns all bundles, whether they are fragments or not. For a given [Bundle](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html) object, what is the best way to tell if this is a fragment or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best way:

`(bundle.adapt(BundleRevision.class).getTypes() & BundleRevision.TYPE_FRAGMENT) != 0`

Comment: Yeah, that's much more explicit than my way. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that this is a new API in OSGi 4.3. Also be aware that adapt() can return null if you lose the race condition just as the bundle is being uninstalled.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way: use [Bundle.getHeaders()](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#getHeaders%28%29) to look for the [Fragment-Host](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment-Host) header. If it is present, it's a fragment.

Comment: Answering my own question for now with the best way I know of... if this is wrong or there are better ways I will award the answer elsewhere!

Answer (score 1):

According to the OSGi Core Specification Release 4, Version 4.2, there is also the `PackageAdmin` service, which provides access to the structural information about bundles, e.g. determine whether a given bundle is a fragment or not.

```
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin;

PackageAdmin packageAdmin = ...; // I assume you know this

Bundle hostBundle = ...;         // I assume you know this
Bundle fragmentBundle = ...;     // I assume you know this

assertFalse(PackageAdmin.BUNDLE_TYPE_FRAGMENT, packageAdmin.getBundleType(hostBundle);
assertEquals(PackageAdmin.BUNDLE_TYPE_FRAGMENT, packageAdmin.getBundleType(fragmentBundle);
```

Apparently, in OSGi 4.3, the `PackageAdmin` service seems to be [deprecated](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/service/packageadmin/PackageAdmin.html) and should be replaced by the `org.osgi.framework.wiring` package.